# Change cell size in a UICOLLECTIONVIEW with slider

Tags: ios, slider

i want to change the size of cells in a uicollectionview with a slider but i cant find how to do.

its like in the macOs finder when you see icons, you can change the size of it with a slider.

I want it for an iPad app

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hook up your slider to the above method (for value changed), then use the following method to define the height:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.slider.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly perfect, i want for a uicollection view so i need to change with:

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Return the size of each cell to draw
    CGSize cellSize = (CGSize) { .width = 320, .height = self.slider.value};
    return cellSize;
}
```